# visual studio 2013 git clone puts project files in wrong folder

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2013, clone

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Pro. I set the default repository location to a folder on my development drive, which is I: on my system. I then cloned a repo from GIthub. A folder with the project name was created in the repos folder on I, but the only item in it is the .git folder. All of the project folders and files were written to the C: drive at the root. I am new to git, but in my searches everything I have found suggests I did this properly and I cannot find anyone else having this issue. If anyone has ideas to find what might be happening here I would sure appreciate it.

THanks,
Rob M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I should come back to this. I finally found that .gitconfig in C:\Users had an entry setting the WORKTREE to \ , this was overiding undefined WORKTREEs in any project I cloned and writng the trunk to C:.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hi Rob have you signed into github from git bash, sounds like you have not pushed to your git repository. 
Try :git push -am origin master
if all else fails have a look at the basics of git hub again here is a link that helped me.
visit:http://readwrite.com/2013/09/30/understanding-github-a-journey-for-beginners-part-1.

Hope this helps!!!!

Comment: I signed on to github from within VS using integrated git, I hit clone and pointed it to the repo url and selected the local repo directory, on my I: drive,  as the destination. VS message said it succeeded but repo contains new folder for the project with only a >git folder while the project folders and files were written to my C: drive. Thanks for the link, I am checking it out but I have read several tuts already on this which state that the procedure I followed should have put the project files in the repo folder with the .git folder.

Comment: I ran git status and all of the project files are being reported deleted.